# Add values of the text fields and show the sum

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to add few numbers using angularjs and it seems if i have input type="text" then it does not add the numbers and if i have input type="numbers" then my directive does not work

input type="text" does not add up
input type="number" directive does not work

I have put together the sample that demonstrates the above problem
http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/khh2fyjs/1/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <input type="text" ng-model="a1" numbers-only="numbers-only" maxlength="4"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="b1" numbers-only="numbers-only" maxlength="4" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="c1" numbers-only="numbers-only" maxlength="4"/>
    <br/>
    <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="d1" numbers-only="numbers-only" maxlength="4" />
    <br>
   payed <input type="text" ng-model="e1" numbers-only="numbers-only"   />
    <hr/>
     <h3>{{ e1 - (a1+b1+c1+d1) | currency}} </h3>  
</div>
```

Comment: I believe this is happening because when you use input-type="number", the parser isn't firing when you use letters. This means that the numbers-only directive is unable to filter them out.  I'm facing the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

The numbers don't add up in the first example because they are strings.  It's just concatenating all the strings together.  To get that to work, use `parseInt` to convert them to numbers before adding.

re: the Directive, shouldn't the last line be (note 'de1' instead of ee1)

`<h3>{{ de1 - (aa1+bb1+cc1+dd1) | currency}} </h3>`

Comment: yes it was typo but the `parseInt ` does not work can you try in jsfiddle and post it here?